# How do i do these queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I am trying to do these queries for a homework of a subject that the teacher didn't teach us, and none of my classmates can do it either, I have these 4 tables to MySQL

**Activity**

> ```
> idActivity | nameActivity           | idDepartment
> ---------: | :--------------------- | -----------:
>          1 | hiring                 |            1
>          2 | payroll                |            1
>          3 | purchasing             |            2
>          4 | quotes                 |            2
>          5 | Customer contact       |            3
>          6 | Customer agreement     |            3
>          7 | marketing              |            3
>          8 | Product placement      |            2
>          9 | Collection of products |            2
>         10 | assitance              |            1
>         11 | Product delivery       |            3
>         12 | Check-in and check-out |            4
>         13 | offers                 |            3
> ```

**Employee**

> ```
> idEmployee | NameEmployee | Salary | idDepartment
> ---------: | :----------- | -----: | -----------:
>         10 | Maria        |   4000 |            1
>         20 | Jorge        |   3000 |            2
>         30 | Leonor       |   5000 |            3
>         40 | Patricia     |   3000 |            2
>         50 | Gilberto     |   2000 |            4
>         60 | Gonzalo      |   7000 |            2
>         70 | Beatriz      |   3000 |            1
>         80 | Ana          |   5000 |            3
>         90 | Manuel       |   2000 |            4
>        100 | Silvestre    |   7000 |            1
>        110 | Alejandra    |   5000 |            2
>        120 | Fernando     |   2000 |            1
>        130 | Joaquin      |   4000 |            4
>        140 | Pedro        |   4000 |            4
>        150 | Pablo        |   2500 |            3
> ```

**Department**

> ```
> idDepartment | nameDepartment
> -----------: | :-------------
>            1 | staff         
>            2 | Purchasing    
>            3 | Sells         
>            4 | finances
> ```

**Activity-Employee**

> ```
> idEmployee | idActivity
> ---------: | ---------:
>         10 |          1
>         10 |          2
>         20 |          3
>         20 |          4
>         30 |          5
>         30 |          6
>         30 |          7
>         50 |          8
>         50 |          9
>         70 |         10
>         90 |          8
>        100 |          1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=be77df13c19efabbc0b870f4ae050b9a)*

Some columns have the same name because primary and foreign keys, the primary keys are in the tables that have there names. What am I trying to do are some queries like:

- Show employees names, name of the department that they belong to, and name of the activities that they do, grouping by activity (Group by).
- **Using Subqueries** Show employees names, name of the department that they belong to, and name of the activities that they do, grouping by activity (Group by).

We tried some queries but the employee name just repeat itself, and didn't group by activities.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f7AkdjHYltKxg640diUZfD2zs2gM-sol/view?usp=sharing

Hopefully someone can help us, we are kinda desperate :(
And sorry for not knowing how to put directly the tables in here, it's my first post in here:(

Comment: The `grouping by activity (group by)` part makes no sense (to me). `GROUP BY` takes groups of input rows and Aggregates each group to a single output row. There's no mention in the questions, however, of any aggregation. (It's possible the author made a mistake and wants similar rows next to each other, which would be `ORDER BY`, not `GROUP BY`.) I'd ask the teacher for some example results, so at least you know the type of expected output, rather than a wooly and ambiguous requirement.

Comment: It might also help to post the queries you've tried, and the output. BTW, you can paste tables as text. That's actually the preferred method, since unlike images they can be copied and searched :-)

Comment: Right now, as I am concerned, we are using de Group By for things like alphabetical order, because none other query is like this one, just appears like alphabetical. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f7AkdjHYltKxg640diUZfD2zs2gM-sol/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post. In addition, this is a question and answer site. Question is singular, not plural. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: @ElianRobles - Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71520422/edit) the question and add your attempted queries (and results) as *text*, not as an image!

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
NameEmployee,
group_concat(nameActivity) nameActivity,
(select nameDepartment from Department where idDepartment=tmpx.idDepartment) as DeptName from (select  t1.NameEmployee,
(select distinct nameActivity from Activity where idActivity=t2.idActivity) as nameActivity,
(select distinct idDepartment from Activity where idActivity=t2.idActivity) as idDepartment
from Employee t1 join `Activity-Employee` t2 
on t1.idEmployee=t2.idEmployee) as tmpx GROUP BY tmpx.NameEmployee;
```

**Check if it works for u**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It gives me the error #1054 the column 'nameActivity' on field list is unknown